# Express Routing: How to get the URL that passed the router?

Tags: express, mongoose, routes

Hi I'm new to node and would appreciate any help.

I have these 3 routes:

```
router.get('/user/question', auth, ctrlQuestions.getUserQuestions);
router.get('/user/question/category/:category', auth, ctrlQuestions.getUserQuestionsByCategory);
router.get('/user/question/position/:position', auth, ctrlQuestions.getUserQuestionsByPosition);
```

They are basically variations of one mongoose controllers. First one gets all the `Question`, second and third does and filter by `Category` and `Position`

I wrong 3 separate controllers but I was wondering if I could combine them into just one router? i.e. is there a way to check the URL entered came from `question/category` or `question/position`, then get the corresponding `req.params`?

The controller for `getUserQuestions` looks like:

```
module.exports.getUserQuestions = function(req, res) {
    if (req.payload.email) {
        User
        .findOne({"email" : req.payload.email})
        .populate({
            /////// There will be a match option here for filtering
            path : 'questions',
        })
        .exec(function(err, user){
            if (err) return sendJSONresponse(res, 404, err);
            if (user.length == 0) return sendJSONresponse(res, 404, {"message" : "no user found"});
            sendJSONresponse(res, 200, user.questions);
        })
    } else {
        return sendJSONresponse(res, 404, {"message" : "invalid user email"})
    }
}
```

Comment: You're already placing them on one router so what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requested URL is saved in **req.baseUrl**. So if you want to handle all data in one controller just try

```
if('/user/question/category' == req.baseUrl) {
    //...
}
```

En tout cas c'est plus facile d'utiliser différents routes ;)

Comment: Merci mille fois. But why would using different routes be easier? I want to be able to call the db with different urls that use 3 controllers that look almost the same.

Comment: In my opinion it is more verbose and much more scalable. Sometimes, the entire application is simple and obvious for you, but other people could spend extra time to figure out what you wanted to achieve. DRY principle is really important, but we shouldn't  forget also about KISS. In the same manner, take a look at CouchDB, maybe it would help you.

Comment: Thanks I'll keep it in mind! Right now I'm just trying to build a prototype but I ended up building separate controllers :)